# Localization of a module at a prime ideal and local behavior.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, localization

Let $M$ be an $R$-module ($R$ commutative with unity) and suppose that given $\mathfrak{p}\subset R$ a prime ideal we have $M_{\mathfrak{p}}\cong R_{\mathfrak{p}}^n$.

Is then true that we can find an element $f \in R$ such that $M_f \cong R^n[f^{-1}]$?

Comment: Note: This is called *generic freeness*.

Comment: @MooS Wouldn't that be what you'd call if it you looked at the *generic* point? Generic freeness, to me, means that you're the trivial bundle on a dense open. That is related to this problem, and its solution, assuming that $M$ is coherent, say, and $\mathfrak{p}=0$ (where $R$ is a domain). For example, if $R$ is disconnected and $M$ is free on one component, but not even a vector bundle on the other, I don't think I'd call that generic freeness.

Comment: Of course it is not the exact formulation, but it is closely related and can be even considered as a generalization. One often calls generalizations by the same name, for an example look at Krull's Principal ideal theorem.

Comment: Question: Do we need $M$ to be finitely presented or just finitely generated?

Comment: You will at least need finitely presented as the following example shows. Let $R$ be the polynomial ring in infinitely many variables $x_i,y_i$ modulo $x_iy_i$ for all $i$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be the prime ideal generated by all the $x_i$s and let $M=R/\mathfrak{p}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes...assuming that $M$ is finitely generated (if not see Mohan's helpful comment below).

Hint: The isomorphism $R^n_{\mathfrak{p}}\to M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ sends the basis vectors $e_i$ to elements of the form $\displaystyle \sum_j f_{i,j} m_j$ where $f_i\in R_{\mathfrak{p}}$. This isomorphism really only needs to have that the $f_{i,j}$ make sense, and this really only requires inverting finitely many denominators.

Comment: If $M$ is not finitely generated, this is false in general. For example, take $R$ to be a domain, $\mathfrak{p}=0$, $K$ the fraction field and let $M=K$.

Comment: @Mohan Oops, of course! I sort of assume everything in life is coherent :P Thanks--will edit.

Comment: Are you suggesting to take $f$ as the product of all denominators of $f_{i,j}$?

Comment: @Abellan I am. $ $

Comment: I hope that this is my last comment. Let us suppose that each $f_{i,j}=\frac{1}{g_{i,j}}$ and we define $f=\prod\limits_{(i,j)}f_{i,j}$  and $\gamma_{i,j}=\prod\limits_{(k,l)\neq (i,j)}f_{k,l}$. Then I define the following morphism,

$R^n[g^{-1}] \to M[g^{-1}], e_i \mapsto \sum\limits_j\frac{\gamma_{i,j}}{g}m_j$. This is clearly injective. Where do I used that the module is finite generated? To show surjectivity?

Comment: @Abellan Somehow, I don't see why it is clearly injective. Something one can do is the following. Suppose $M_p = R_p(m_1,\dots, m_n)$. One can assume that $m_i \in R$. Consider the exact sequence $0 \to \ker \phi \to R^n \to M \to coker \phi \to 0$, where $\phi(e_i) = m_i$. Localization is exact. Hence $(\ker \phi)_P = (coker~ \phi)_P = 0$. So there exist a,b not in $P$ such that $(\ker \phi)_a = (coker~ \phi)_b = 0$. Take $f = ab$. The finiteness condition is necessary in order to find such $a,b$ as in Mohan's comment.

Comment: It looked clear before your comment. Thanks a lot for your insights!